# Unexpected behavior of the following Java program

Tags: java, multithreading

In following java program `Thread.sleep(1000)` is called after for loop. However, it is getting Interrupted before printing all value. Inside the run method, it should print all value then go for sleep, Why I am getting unexpected behavior of the following Java program.

Output:

```
java.lang.InterruptedException: sleep interrupted
Value=0
    at java.lang.Thread.sleep(Native Method)
Value=1
    at com.thread.TestThread.run(InterruptThread.java:21)
Value=2
Value=3
Value=4
Value=5
Value=6
Value=7
Value=8
Value=9
```

**Interrupted Program**

```
public class InterruptThread {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        TestThread thread = new TestThread();
        thread.start();
        thread.interrupt();
    }
}

class TestThread extends Thread{
    @Override
    public void run() {
        try {
            for(int i=0; i<10; i++){
                System.out.println("Value="+ i);
            }
            Thread.sleep(1000);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            System.out.println("Thread is interrupted");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Well you immediately interrupt the thread after calling `start()`.  What else were you expecting it to do?

Comment: Just a guess: you are confused by `stderr`.  There are two output streams in a Java program.  `stdout` and `stderr`.  Because there are two streams and they are asynchronous, they can output independently and will frequently stomp on top of each other on the screen.  You're seeing the error message first just because `stderr` happened to print faster than `stdout` in this case.

Comment: What markspace told is true. If you use System.nanoTime() in the S.O.P , you can see the time diff (e.g) System.out.println("Value="+ i +" "+System.nanoTime()); & System.out.println("Thread is interrupted" +" "+System.nanoTime());

Answer (score 2):

> ```
> public void printStackTrace()
> ```
>
> Prints this throwable and its backtrace to **the standard error stream.**

You print values to **the standard output stream**, so you basically have two streams involved. Since they flush at different times, the order of messages is truly unpredictable.

<sup>Run the snippet several times, and you may get lucky and see the order you were expecting :)</sup>

Comment: You can use `printStackTrace(System.out);`  to avoid this issue +1